# Need Help Creating a Storybook Tab that loads in MDX Files

Tags: javascript, storybook, storybook-addon

I've spent the last day trying to create two additional tabs within my Storybook. By default it shows you the "Canvas" and "Docs" sections. I want to add two more. I was one for "Design Guidelines" and one for "Coding Guidelines". Both those tabs would load an mdx file located in the same directory that as the component stories.

I was hoping to have a file tree structure like-

```
Accordion.stories.mdx
Accordion.design.mdx
Accordion.coding.mdx
```

Where I can specify docs for designers to use in the design tab and coding for engineers/devs. Right now our solutions a kinda mix and it's harder to find stuff.

I wrote this code, but nothing is working. Seems to have a lot of magic underneath the hood. Can someone point me in the right direction or want some quick side work? I'll pay (Zelle, Paypal, Venmo) lol.

```
/**
         * Design Guidelines Tab for Storybook
         *
         * This code creates a Storybook tab for displaying design guidelines
         * by loading an MDX file located in the same directory as the component story.
         * The MDX file should have the same name as the component with ".design.mdx" extension.
         */
        
        import React from 'react';
        import { addons, types } from '@storybook/addons';
        import { DocsContainer } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
        import { join, dirname, basename } from 'path';
        
        // Define the title for the custom tab
        const tabTitle = 'Design Guidelines';
        
        /**
         * DesignGuidelinesTab Component
         *
         * Renders the design guidelines content for a specific story.
         * It loads the MDX file based on the story's file path and displays the content.
         *
         * @param {string} storyPath - The file path of the story component
         * @returns {React.Component} - The DesignGuidelinesTab component
         */
        const DesignGuidelinesTab = ({ storyPath }) => {
          // Create the file path for the design guidelines MDX file
          const designFilePath = join(dirname(storyPath), `${basename(storyPath, '.js')}.design.mdx`);
        
          // State to hold the content of the design guidelines MDX file
          const [designContent, setDesignContent] = React.useState('');
        
          // Fetch the design guidelines content from the MDX file
          React.useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchDesignContent() {
              try {
                const response = await fetch(designFilePath);
                const content = await response.text();
                setDesignContent(content);
              } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error loading design file: ${error}`);
              }
            }
        
            fetchDesignContent();
          }, [designFilePath]);
        
          // Log the file path and content of the design guidelines MDX file
          console.log('Design file path:', designFilePath);
          console.log('Design file content:', designContent);
        
          return (
            <DocsContainer context={{}}>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: designContent }} />
            </DocsContainer>
          );
        };
        
        // Register the Design Guidelines Tab addon
        addons.register('designGuidelinesTab', () => {
          addons.add('designGuidelinesTab', {
            type: types.TAB,
            title: tabTitle,
            route: ({ storyId }) => `/design-guidelines-tab/${storyId}`,
            match: ({ viewMode, storyId }) =>
              viewMode === 'design-guidelines-tab' && storyId.endsWith('--design-guidelines'),
            render: ({ active, storyId, storyContext }) => {
              // Log the file path of the current story component
              console.log('Story file path:', storyContext.parameters.fileName);
        
              // Render the DesignGuidelinesTab component if the tab is active
              if (active) {
                return <DesignGuidelinesTab storyPath={storyContext.parameters.fileName} />;
              }
              return null;
            },
          });
        });
```

Comment: I'm all for jokes, but maybe don't offer payment on here XD